# Facebook style change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dhtml

Im searching a code split. I want to a link first click run a MySQL query and change link.

I found it this, but is only change text:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready  
    // (a little sooner than page load)   
    $('#slickbox').hide();

    // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link    
    $('a#slickbox-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').slideToggle(400);
        return false;   
    }); 
}); 
</script> 
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show box' ? 'Hide box' : 'Show box');
```

Example:
Facebook like button =>

> **Like** (56 likes)
>   Click (update likes ...... ..... likecount+=1)
>   **Unlike** (57 likes)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute an AJAX request in your `onclick` handler. This will need to interact with some sort of webservice or script that makes the SQL query.

The norm is to use AJAX to send a request to a PHP script that uses the [MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) to interact with a MySQL database.

Googling any of those keywords will give you many examples and tutorials that you can follow.